# Python pip show me error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, batch-file, pip, lxml

My OS is win10 (64bit) and using Python 3.5+. I tried to install `lxml` with `pip`.

```
pip install lxml
```

But I got this error

```
building 'lxml.etree' extension  error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

also I tried this solution but nothing changed

[error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Did you try installing a [pre-built version of lxml](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) from Christoph Gohlke's site?

Comment: Yes. I found some error: C:\Users\asad\lib>pip install lxml-3.6.4-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
lxml-3.6.4-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Why did you try to install a 32 bit, Python 2.7 version? This one should work on your system: "lxml‑3.6.4‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl". I can't test it myself: I have a 32 bit machine, and I don't run Windows.

Comment: lxml-3.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl this version successfully installed and worked, thanks,

Comment: It is not solved. Why did you mark it duplicate? Today i was trying to install "pip install flask-mysqldb" it was same error. I was trying more and more. I cant. Please unmark duplicate it.

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2817869/4014959) because it's essentially the same problem, and you said that installing a pre-built binary from the Gohlke site (as suggested in one of the answers of the linked question) solved your problem. Do you understand _why_ you get this error? If you want this question re-opened you need to edit the question, explaining why _none_ of the linked answers helped you. You also need to give details of your build environment, in particular, the C compiler(s) that are installed.

Comment: FWIW, the Stack Exchange policy is to close duplicate questions because we want the answers of such questions to be concentrated in one place. That makes it easier to find all the suggested answers and to compare them by the score they've achieved.